# Select Top 50 from left table using Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  TOP(50)  *  FROM [Cars]
LEFT JOIN [Colors] ON [Cars].[ModelId] = [Colors].[ModelId]
```

Returns **50 rows** but i want **50 cars**, because there are multiple colors per car Top(50) is not working.

Comment: 1) Using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless, because it doesn't reveal with respect to which columns 50 should be taken, 2) you should add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (Select TOP 50 * FROM Cars) cars
LEFT JOIN [Colors] colors ON cars.[ModelId] = colors.[ModelId]
```

Found the answer, this works.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are not using any information from Colors table. In this case
you need not join with Colors table.

```
SELECT  TOP(50)  *  FROM [Cars]
```

If you are looking to get each color of a car then probably you should use a list aggregate function for colors along with cars.
Assuming color is the column name in Colors

```
SELECT  TOP(50)  *,
                 STRING_AGG([Colors].color, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY color) AS colors
FROM [Cars]
LEFT JOIN [Colors] ON [Cars].[ModelId] = [Colors].[ModelId]
```